# Does `Network.loadingFinished` event include `Network.requestServedFromCache` in chrome DevTools?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to using Selenium to analyse the performance of certain pages. I have a question about the Network events.

When a HTTP request was sent, it will fire a `Network.requestWillBeSent` in Chrome DevTools Performance Log. If it fails, it will fire `Network.loadingFailed`, succeeds then `Network.loadingFinished`. How about those cached ones, will both `Network.loadingFinished` and `Network.requestServedFromCache` fire or just `Network.requestServedFromCache`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If loading from cache, both `Network.loadingFinished` and `Network.requestServedFromCache` will be fired